# how to achieve 'if not-then' like thing in sql where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have encountered a problem with sql.

I have a table `Person`.

```
create table Person(id int primary key, name varchar(30), postal_code int, country varchar(20));

insert into Person values(1, 'Aagam Jain', 12345, 'India');
insert into Person values(2, 'Akshay Jain', 12346, 'India');
insert into Person values(3, 'Aman Jain', 12347, 'USA');
insert into Person values(4, 'Abhinav Jain', 12348, 'UK');
insert into Person values(5, 'Akki Jain', 12349, 'Germany');
insert into Person values(6, 'Amar Jain', 12348, 'UK');

SELECT * FROM Person;
```

[image]

Here is the dummy data with table schema will help you in answering quickly.

I want all records of the table except For Country India I just want record with pincode `12345`.

Here is the sample output format.

[image]

For all other country I want all records, But for India I just want records with postal code '12345';

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `where Country <> 'India' or pincode = 12345`

Comment: You say you've encountered a problem, but you haven't said what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple application of logical operators `AND` / `OR` with parentheses `( )` should do the trick. Try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM Person 
WHERE (country = 'India' and postal_code = '12345') 
OR country != 'India'
```

Based on [@jarlh's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52480024/select-pin-code-12345-if-india-select-all-pincodes-for-rest/52480061#comment91900962_52480024), neater logic would be:

```
SELECT * FROM Person 
WHERE country != 'India' OR postal_code = '12345'
```

Comment: Thanks working :)

Comment: @AagamJain happy to help :) Do consider accepting as answer. Thanks

Comment: @AagamJain Also, jarlh's comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52480024/select-pin-code-12345-if-india-select-all-pincodes-for-rest/52480061#comment91900962_52480024  is neater logic

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Person
WHERE p.country = 'India' OR p.postal_code = '12345'
```

Comment: Not correct giving two rows of where country is India.

Comment: Sorry Got you just make `p.country = 'India'` to `p.country != 'India'` and also give alias to table.

Comment: @AagamJain . . . I interpreted the question as "(Select pin code 12345) (if India select all pincodes for rest)", not "(Select pin code 12345 if India) (select all pincodes for rest)".

Comment: Sorry My bad. :)